# user reject every 2nd edit suggestion

Tags: discussion, support

User @ManshviBirla https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/26509/manashvi-birla

rejects every 2nd edit suggestion,

I come to notice when she rejects my 2 tag edits(though its approved by other users).

I dont know what she looking for edit suggestion approval as she has 50% rejections in edit suggestion.

You can see in below screenshot or this url https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/128751

[image]

Comment: we are looking on this.

Comment: Thanks @AmitBera

Answer (score 4):

Murtuza Zabuawala, Thanks for notice such things.

I don't think the reason of reject by Manshvi is not fully wrong over this  edit
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/128751

Let me explain,First please check her reason of rejection at the edit

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible.
>
> Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability

.

She asked the more brief description on over the tag that validates and we cannot ignore that.

In my view, you have provided more detail above that tag at the **wiki**  field than might be she does not have an option of reject of your edit.

In such case, we can suggest that @ManshviBirla instead of rejecting more edits, improve those edit, so that it will improve the content of MSE.

Comment: but she has state of 50% rejection and I don't understand why, even I am strict with edit approvals but hardly 2 or 3% rejection

Comment: Ya,  she has 50% rejection. We will check in more detail  and if require then we will contact them]